# I need help with an elementary number theory proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, real-numbers

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$. Consider the following theorem: $a\mid c  \land  b\mid c\land \gcd(a,b)=1 \Rightarrow ab\mid c$. I'm currently attempting to understand a proof in which there is a step that I am unable to understand and the authers claim that the aforementioned  theorem justifies that step. Let $n_1,...n_k, N\in\mathbb{Z}:\gcd(n_i,n_j)=1, i\neq j \land n_i\mid N, i=1,...,k$. They claim that iteratively applying the theorem above leads to the conclusion that $n_1,...n_k\mid N$. It seems quite intuitive to me that this result ought to be true but I am unable to prove it. Could anyone help me? I get that for example if $k=3$ then $n_1n_2\mid N \land n_3\mid N$ is true but I fail to see how this implies $n_1n_2n_3\mid N$ since I don't know if $\gcd(n_1n_2,n_3)=1$ is true or false.

Comment: If $\gcd(n_1,n_3)=1$ and $\gcd(n_2,n_3)=1$, then $\gcd(n_1n_2,n_3)=?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Suppose $\gcd(a,c) = \gcd(b,c) = 1$.
Then $\gcd(ab,c) = 1$.

$\textit{Proof}$

Suppose with a view to contradiction that $\gcd(ab,c)\neq 1$. Let $p$ be a prime that divides both $ab$ and $c$. Then by Euclid's lemma, $p|a$ or $p|b$. But then either $\gcd(a,c) \ge p>1$ or $\gcd(b,c) \ge p>1$, a contradiction.

Using this result, I think you can do the rest :)